# Global styles for FontImageSource property

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have following button in my Xamarin Forms application

```xml
    <Button
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="0">
        <Button.ImageSource>
            <FontImageSource Glyph="&#xF072;" FontFamily="{StaticResource IconFont}" Color="{StaticResource BaseColor}"/>
        </Button.ImageSource>
    </Button>
```

where `IconFont` is:

```xml
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" x:Key="IconFont">
        <On Platform="Android" Value="materialdesignicons-webfont.ttf#Material design" />
        <On Platform="iOS" Value="Material Design Icons" />
    </OnPlatform>
```

Everything is working fine. Now, because all of my icons are in `materialdesignicons-webfont` and I will never use different icons I decided to move entire styling to App.xaml. I would like to set default properties like that:

```xml
    <Style TargetType="FontImageSource">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource IconFont}" />
        <Setter Property="Color" Value="{StaticResource BaseColor}" />
    </Style>
```

And use button by passing glyph only.

```xml
    <Button
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="0">
        <Button.ImageSource>
            <FontImageSource Glyph="&#xF072;"/>
        </Button.ImageSource>
    </Button>
```

1. For some reasons Icon is not rendered without specifying `FontFamily` and `Color` directly in `FontImageSource`. Am I missing something?
2. Is there some way to call my button in simpler way? F.e.

```xml
    <Button
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="0"
        MDGlyph="&#xF072;" />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to style a `FontImageSource` currently. It still isn't possible even with Maui but the [original github issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6421) has been copied to an [issue on the github for Maui](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13474).

Answer (score 3):

have you tried this:

```xml
    <Style x:Key="ButtonWithFontImageSource" TargetType="Button">
       <Setter Property="ImageSource">
            <FontImageSource 
                FontFamily="{StaticResource FontIcons}"
                Glyph="{DynamicResource IconText}">
            </FontImageSource>
        <Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Hi, this  does not seems to work for me, I am getting: Error The PropertyName of Button.ImageSourceProperty is not ImageSource.